# Merging CSS into html

Tags: html, css, merge

I had to make mail template that looks good and I did. Sent from normal client it looks good, but if i'm sending it from system that I use it doesn't read CSS in head section at all. Is there a tool that can inteligently merge CSS into html? The file is quite huge and adding manually style to every  would be long and hard

Comment: having it in head should be ok. What client are you having problems with? there are a lot of css attributes that email clients dont support.

Comment: Services like Campaign Monitor can automatically place your CSS inline for you. A big timesaver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some email clients ignore `<style>` tags altogether, you'll need to inline the styles. [This tool](http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php) should help.

Comment: It's close, but my client doesn't ignore style tag, just displays its content. And this tool doesn't solve my problems - everything is as it was - but it's something like that that I'm looking for.

Comment: The tool linked in the answer doesn't work any more. MailChimp has a [tool to inline the styles](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/), though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<style type="text/css"></style>` in your header tag to merge the css and html into one file. Then paste your css in between the style tags.

Comment: As I said I do have it in my header tag and it doesn't work. It looks great in browser, also sent from conventional mail client, but when I do it in sysaid (software I use) it just doesn't work. I wrote mail to their helpdesk, but they just said they doesn't support CSS.

Answer (score 0):

this is the most recommended way with an external link of CSS folder.

you can also combine CSS in HTML by using inline CSS. To do this, add your CSS code directly to the HTML elements that you want to style. For example: My Website

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).